# Returning null from factory method in Spring

Tags: spring

In my spring configuration file, I have declared one bean which is instantiated via a static factory method. The factory method invokes some remote services. The factory method returns null incase it is not able to access the remote service.

My problem everything goes wrong when the factory method returns null. and The spring initialization fails.

I really want to set the bean to null, if the factory method is not able to invoke the remote service.

Part of my config file is as follows :

```
<bean id="Helper" class="com.test.Helper">
   <constructor-arg ref="myBean" />
</bean>
<bean id="myBean" class="com.test.Factory" factory-method="getBean" />
```

the getBean() method is as follows:

```
Factory {
      public static Bean getBean() throws Exception{

             try {
                //Invokes some Remote Services and does some processing
                ....
                ....
                //returns bean object
            }catch(Exception e) {
                return null;
            }    
      }

  }
```

Please help me how can I solve this.

Comment: Do you have an stack trace, and some code?

Comment: Don't return `null`. You'll get NullPointerExceptions and you won't be able to work out whether it's because you've misconfigured Spring, or the server not being available. See the Null Object pattern for what default to return.

Answer (score 2):

Use `MethodInvokingFactoryBean` like so:

```
<bean id="myBean"
      class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.MethodInvokingFactoryBean">
 <property name="targetClass"><value>com.test.Factory</value></property>
 <property name="targetMethod"><value>getBean</value></property>
</bean>
```

Answer (score -2):

you can return null . but be sure that b'coz of this null value there will be no NullPointerException raised . if it is raising just keep a simple if condition or return the control back from where it come or handle as think is perfect